# hostnamectl shows error: "Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory"

Tags: centos, hostname, ansible

When I try to set `hostname` with an ansible module, I get

```
TASK [set hostname] **************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.1.38.15]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Command failed rc=1, out=, err=Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory\n"}
```

Interestingly when I ssh to the computer and I try to set hostname with `hostnamectl` I also get an error.

```
bash-4.2# hostnamectl set-hostname foo.bar.com
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```

I believe these two issues are related, but `dbus` shows that it's running,

```
● dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-01-07 09:04:45 CST; 2h 28min ago
```

What could the problem be? I am using Centos 7.

Apparently, when I `strace` `hostnamectl` I get

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"}, 33) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

And I can confirm that `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket` is not present

The ansible play is

```
- name: set hostname
  hostname
    name: cp-1-2.foo.bar.com
```

Comment: Did you try to restart `dbus`?

Answer (score 6):

> I can confirm that `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket` is not present.

There is your problem right there, then.  `/var/run` should symbolically link to `/run`, and `/run/dbus/system_bus_socket` was created as a consequence of `dbus.socket`.

No amount of fiddling with `dbus.service` will fix either of those if they are not the case, by the way.  Fix the symbolic link, or re-initialize the *socket*.

Comment: "re-initialize the socket": This can be done using `systemctl start dbus.socket`.

Comment: thank you, that did it!

Answer (score 1):

your symbolic link to /var/run is broken. recreate the symbolic link and you should be good to go.

```
sudo rm /var/run -R
sudo ln -s /run /var
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).